I need to copy a rewrite rule from IIS into NGINX
I have this rewrite rule in IIS that I want to migrate to NGINX but I can't get it quite right.
            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.cfm/{R:1}" />
            </rule>

I am also using NGINX as a proxy pass for a dev site on ColdFusion.
    location / {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.cfm/$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:38411;
    }

With this configuration, I end up with an endless re-direct where I have a re-direct to a login page.
It seems like this should be an easy thing to replicate, maybe the interaction with proxy_pass is causing the endless re-direct issues.
